# Equivilant to ProjectReference that doesn't create a binary dependency

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

Is there a way with the .NET Core SDK to have the build dependency graph adjusted like using `ProjectReference` without the actual reference being made *and* not adjust the solution file?

In some detail, I have 2 projects `Service` and `Client`. The `Service` project is generating a Swagger/Open API file. The `Client` project is a NuGet package that consumes the generated file to code generate some C# code. I would want to instruct MSBuild to rebuild `Service` if it changes anytime `Client` is built. Using `ProjectReference` would make a hard reference and include the service dll in the package. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to cobble something together using some obscure options:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="OtherProject">
      <!-- Hacks around to get the service to build first -->
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
      <SetTargetFramework>TargetFramework=netcoreapp2.1</SetTargetFramework>
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

For example, the MSBuild project including this code targeted .NET Standard 2.0. The reference is built using .NET Core 2.1. The `SetTargetFramework` eliminates the incompatibility error.